# One correct answer and one hack, that does work better for me - which to accept?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722076/adding-a-new-index-row-to-an-existing-dataframe-and-sorting-by-it/) and so far it has two answers.

The first one by Pedro M Duarte, which I feel is the correct answer, and the second one, by Nader Hisham, which does ignore the index as a way of sorting, but rather "pollutes" my data, with some unrelated sorting info.

But, I can easily get rid of that "pollution" after doing the sorting, and so it works easily and fast. The other solution, works perfectly fine on my test data, but for my real dataset it requires much more typing work and is much more error prone that the hack.

Thus, I quickly gave up on the proper solution (which would have many benefits otherwise, such as retaining my distance info in the index, for possible further sorting or such), in favor of the quicker and (for my specific situation) less errorprone hack.

**So which answer to accept?**

The one which did get the job done for me, even though it ignored parts of my question, or the one which looks like its correct, but I could not test it on other data than my test data?

I am leaning towards accepting the nicely working hack, and editing an explantion into the question.

Comment: First things first, if you feel both answers are useful upvote them. As for accepting... you don't really have to accept any answer.

Comment: But  if there is an answer that did answer the question, I should. And there are two that did, but I can only accept one.

Comment: I would upvote both answers, but accept the one that you actually ended up using. Because you haven't been able to verify if the other one actually works for you.

Comment: As @Yannis mentioned, technically, you don't _have_ to accept one. ___However___, not accepting _any_ answers is generally frowned upon. Especially if the question has multiple answers that helped you. So no, you don't _have_ to accept one, but you really _should_.

Comment: @Oldskool: Well, I could verify that it works for the test case I posted, so it is technically correct. But there are some issues that I did not foresee since I was not aware of the solution, that might as well also be issues for other folks with a similar question (that whole error prone typing thing), so its very difficult to find the "better" one. I was just hoping for a generally accepted behavior in such a situation. Seems like I have missed a similar question in my searches: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251843/accept-the-correct-answer-or-the-better-solution?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upvoting both surely is a good idea.

As for which one to accept, you shouldn't accept the **answer** that seems to be the correct one to the **question** you asked, but the one that **solves** your **problem**. If there's an answer that solves your problem, then it's just as good as one that answers your actual question, just like in the case when someone answer an other question because the question was wrong.

Apart from this you should also think about others that will arrive with **similar** questions, not with the exact same one of you. If you think that people with the same or similar problems would need the "correct" answer and only in your specific case is the other answer more useful, then you should accept the correct one. But if you feel that others with similar problem could resolve it using the same solution of you, even thou not being the "correct" solution, then you should accept the "better" solution, not the correct one.

And at the end if you feel that your choice, or the difference between the situations where one or the other answer is applicable needs further clarification, you can always **comment** on the answers to help others understand it.